# android local service trouble

Tags: android, service

i have a local service in application, which does some network operation in the asynctask.

In my application there are two activities activity A and activity B.

the life cycle of my service is and activities is like this.

```
In activity A:
1)stop service(in oncreate)

In activity B:
1)start service(in oncreate)
2)bindservice(in oncreate)
3)unbind service(in on destroy)

In service:
1)start download in async task(in oncreate)
2)stop async task(in ondestroy)
```

But the service is keep on running.is there something iam missing?
Thanks

```
FIX:
i need to stop the async task before i call stopService. As the service is busy with asyn task, it will ignore my my stop requests.
1)send a msg to service in intent extra, to stop async task.
2)then call stop service
```

Answer (score 0):

A service will shut down after all bindService() calls have had their corresponding unbindService() calls. If there are no bound clients, then the service will also need stopService() if and only if somebody called startService() on the service.
So you need to call stopService() to stop the service you started in Activity B `1)start service(in oncreate)` in Activity B `onDestroy`.

After reading your comments, the following could do the job for you. No need to bind the service.

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new DownloadTask().execute();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service destroyed!");
    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // download here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            }
    }

}
```

From here stopService in Activity A and startActivity in Activity B.

Comment: i dont want to stop the service in activity B, i want to stop it in A if the user launches the app again --thx

Comment: In that case you need to unbind the service in Activity A.

Comment: i found the flaw, please see the updated post. Thanks a lot for ur help.